# A linear algebra question, I don't understand the answer.

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, numerical-linear-algebra

Question:
There are two vector spaces $V = F^2 = W$. $A = B = {e_1, e_2}$(e is standard basis.)
$$A_1 = ({\begin{gathered}
\begin{Bmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \end{Bmatrix}
\end{gathered} , \begin{gathered}
\begin{Bmatrix} 1 \\ -1 \end{Bmatrix}
\end{gathered}}), B_1 = ({\begin{gathered}
\begin{Bmatrix} 2 \\ 1 \end{Bmatrix}
\end{gathered} , \begin{gathered}
\begin{Bmatrix} -1 \\ 2 \end{Bmatrix}
\end{gathered}})$$
$T:F^2 -> F^2$ is given by the matrix $\begin{gathered} \begin{Bmatrix} 2 & 1 \\ 1 & 0\end{Bmatrix}\end{gathered}$, find $[T]_{A_1, B_1}$. ($A_{11}$ is the first column of the $A_1$)
Mean find the matrix representation with the basis of $A_1, B1$ from $F^2 to F^2$.
My answer:
The basis transform is $A_1 -> A -> B -> B_1$
$A_1 -> A$:
$A_{11} = \alpha_1 e_1 + \alpha_2 e_2 = \begin{gathered}
\begin{Bmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \end{Bmatrix}
\end{gathered}$
$\alpha_1 = \alpha_2 = 1$
$A_{12} = \alpha_3 e_1 + \alpha_4 e_2 = \begin{gathered}
\begin{Bmatrix} 1 \\ -1 \end{Bmatrix}
\end{gathered}$
$\alpha_3 = 1, \alpha_4 = -1$
$[T]_{A_1A} = \begin{gathered}
\begin{Bmatrix} 1 & 1 \\1 & -1 \end{Bmatrix}
\end{gathered}$

$B_1 -> B$:
$B_{11} = \alpha_1 e_1 + \alpha_2 e_2 = \begin{gathered}
\begin{Bmatrix} 2 \\ 1 \end{Bmatrix}
\end{gathered}$
$\alpha_1 = 2, \alpha_2 = 1$
$B_{12} = \alpha_3 e_1 + \alpha_4 e_2 = \begin{gathered}
\begin{Bmatrix} -1 \\ 2 \end{Bmatrix}
\end{gathered}$
$\alpha_3 = -1, \alpha_4 = 2$
$[T]_{B_1B} = \begin{gathered}
\begin{Bmatrix} 2 & -1 \\1 & 2 \end{Bmatrix}
\end{gathered}$
And $[T]_{AB} = \begin{gathered} \begin{Bmatrix} 2 & 1 \\ 1 & 0\end{Bmatrix}\end{gathered}$
Therefore, $[T]_{A_1B_1} = [T]^{-1}_{B_1B}* [T]_{AB}* [T]_{A_1A}$
This is my answer, but the standard answer following :
$T(A_{11}) = [T]_{AB} * A_{11} = \begin{gathered} \begin{Bmatrix} 2 & 1 \\ 1 & 0\end{Bmatrix}\end{gathered}\begin{gathered}
\begin{Bmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \end{Bmatrix}
\end{gathered} = \begin{gathered}
\begin{Bmatrix} 3 \\ 1 \end{Bmatrix}
\end{gathered} = \frac{7}{5} B_{11} + -\frac{1}{5} B_{12}$
$T(A_{12}) = [T]_{AB} * A_{12} = \begin{gathered} \begin{Bmatrix} 2 & 1 \\ 1 & 0\end{Bmatrix}\end{gathered}\begin{gathered}
\begin{Bmatrix} 1 \\ -1 \end{Bmatrix}
\end{gathered} = \begin{gathered}
\begin{Bmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \end{Bmatrix}
\end{gathered} = \frac{3}{5} B_{11} + \frac{1}{5} B_{12}$
Then the $[T]_{A_1B_1} = \begin{gathered} \begin{Bmatrix} \frac{7}{5} & \frac{3}{5} \\ -\frac{1}{5} & \frac{1}{5}\end{Bmatrix}\end{gathered}$
The answer is the same as mine.
I have two questions

1. "$T:F^2 -> F^2$ is given by the matrix", Does the matrix is based on standard basis? I think this matrix is linear transformation $T: F^2 -> F^2 $ with standard basis.\
2. What does the standard answer's means? Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, they mean $\begin{bmatrix}2&1\\1&0\end{bmatrix}$ is the matrix for $T$ in the standard basis.

What does $[T]_{A_1B_1}$ do? If you take an arbitrary vector $v$, it has some expression $$v = v_1A_{11} + v_2A_{12}$$
in terms of the $A_1$ basis. Similarly $w = T(v)$ can be expressed in terms of the $B_1$ basis:
$$w = w_1B_{11} + w_2B_{12}$$

$[T]_{A_1B_1}$ is the matrix that carries $\begin{bmatrix}v_1\\v_2\end{bmatrix}$ to $\begin{bmatrix}w_1\\w_2\end{bmatrix}$. In particular, let $$[T]_{A_1B_1} = \begin{bmatrix}t_{11}&t_{12}\\t_{21}&t_{22}\end{bmatrix}$$

if $v = A_{11}$, then $v_1 = 1, v_2 = 0$, so $$\begin{bmatrix}w_1\\w_2\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}t_{11}&t_{12}\\t_{21}&t_{22}\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}t_{11}\\t_{21}\end{bmatrix}$$
Then $$T(A_{11}) = T(v) = w_1B_{11} + w_2B_{12} = t_{11}B_{11} + t_{21}B_{12}$$
Similarly $$T(A_{12}) = t_{12}B_{11} + t_{22}B_{12}$$

So to find the matrix $[T]_{A_1B_1}$, it is sufficient to express the vectors $T(A_{11})$ and $T(A_{12})$ in terms of the basis $B_1$, and read off the coefficients of $B_{11}, B_{12}$.

This is what the answer in your source does. In terms of the canonical basis, $$A_{11} = \begin{bmatrix}1\\1\end{bmatrix}, A_{12} = \begin{bmatrix}1\\-1\end{bmatrix}$$
Since we know the representation of $T$ in the standard basis, we can calculate
$$T(A_{11}) = \begin{bmatrix}2&1\\1&0\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}1\\1\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}3\\1\end{bmatrix}\\T(A_{12}) = \begin{bmatrix}2&1\\1&0\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}1\\-1\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}1\\1\end{bmatrix}$$
Now we need to express those vectors in terms of $B_1$:
$$\begin{bmatrix}3\\1\end{bmatrix} = t_{11}B_{11} + t_{21}B_{12} = t_{11}\begin{bmatrix}2\\1\end{bmatrix} + t_{21}\begin{bmatrix}1\\-2\end{bmatrix}\\\begin{bmatrix}1\\1\end{bmatrix} = t_{12}B_{11} + t_{22}B_{12} = t_{12}\begin{bmatrix}2\\1\end{bmatrix} + t_{22}\begin{bmatrix}1\\-2\end{bmatrix}$$

This is two systems of two equations in two unknowns. They can be easily solved to give
$t_{11} = \frac 75, t_{21} = -\frac 15$ and $t_{12} = \frac35, t_{22} = \frac 15$.

And therefore

$$[T]_{A_1B_1} = \begin{bmatrix}\frac 75&\frac35\\-\frac 15&\frac 15\end{bmatrix}$$

If you figure out how much actual computation this approach takes as compared to your approach, you will find it is a little easier. In higher dimensions, the amount of calculation drops off more - though not greatly.

Comment: Thanks your answer, but I have a question. What is the difference  between $T(v)$ and $[T]_{A_1 B_1}$? The $T(v)$ is $T(v) = w, w = w_1 B_{11} + w_2 B_{12}$.  I think $T(v)$ is the same as $[T]_{A_1 B_1}$, thus I don't understand why $T(A_{11})$ can be express as $T * A_{11}$?

Comment: All the various $[T]$ are *matrices*. I.e. arrays of numbers. While $T$ itself is a linear transformation of vectors.To make this clearer, consider $T$ to be between two arbitrary (finite dimensional) vector spaces: $T : V \to W$. While vectors in $\Bbb F^2$ are just pairs of numbers, in an arbitrary vector space, they could be anything. Various types of functions are most common. Such a $T$ cannot be identified with a matrix a priori. It is just a mapping from $V$ to $W$. But if also given bases for $V$ and $W$, we can identify each vector with the coefficients in its expansion in the basis.

Comment: If we place those coefficients in 1-column matrices ("column vectors"), we can identify $T$ with the matrix that converts one column vector to the other by matrix multiplication. But that matrix is an array of numbers, not a mapping. And in fact, by choosing other bases, we get different matrices. So the matrices you get are not $T$, which exists without reference to any basis. $[T]_{AB}$ and $[T]_{A_1B_1}$ are two such matrices associated with $T$. $[T]_{A_1A}, [T]_{B_1B}$ are a poor notational choice for two other matrices that are not associated with $T$ itself.

Comment: You *cannot* express $T(A_{11})$ as $T\cdot A_{11}$ (in the sense you mean) because $T$ is a linear transformation, not a matrix. There is no multiplication between maps and vectors. (I put in the parenthetical because it is actually quite common to *write* $T(v)$ as just $Tv$, but this is still the action of a function on an argument, not a true multiplication.)

Comment: Thanks your answer, I understand. Thank u.